# Model-View-Presenter with Delegates, Events and Nested Presenter

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates, mvp

I have a nested set of views as follows:
[image]

Each view has a Presenter where:

- the `MainViewPresenter` has no knowledge of the views or view presenters `ViewA` or `ViewB`
- `ViewA` and `ViewB` are individually managed by their respective presenters and in turn managed by the `SplitViewPresenter`

I have events that will occur in `ViewA` which the `ViewAPresenter` will subscribe to. The `SplitViewPresenter` can subscribe to the child presenter's events and then bubble those up to the `MainViewPresenter`. But this seems like a horrible waste of effort simply to bubble up a button click from `ViewA`.

It seems as though there should be a way to couple some event listener from the `MainViewPresenter` to `ViewA.OnButtonClick`.

In this case where the `MainViewPresenter` has no foreknowledge of what is displayed by other presenters, the Observer/Observable pattern does not seem appropriate. Or maybe there is an implementation using Reactive that would work (Note: .Net 4.0 however)

Would a delegate be the way to go? I know that each event subscription on `ViewA` might require a different delegate which is fine. In this particular instance, the button click will have actions that need to be performed:

- update the database with new information
- add the new model created by `ViewA` to the tree view in the `MainView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the tree view in the `MainView` has a collection for the tree nodes. This collection was already raising `CollectionChanged` events to which the `MainViewPresenter` is subscribed.

The `ViewAPresenter` has a reference to this collection and simply adds the saved model to the collection. In turn the `MainViewPresenter` is notified and the proper node is added.